# Haskell error on text file as input on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, io

I have a Main.hs file with two functions.

```
Module Main where
import Data.List
main :: IO()
main              = interact reverse
functionThatWorks = putStrLn "Ajax"
```

After I set the directory and load Main.hs I have no problem with calling functionThatWorks.
Except when I want to take a text file as input like so:

`Main<in.txt` or `./Main<in.txt`

I get an error saying 'parse error on input 'in' '
Does anyone know I can make this work in the Terminal?

p.s. I use a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `ghci` doesn't understand input redirection like the shell does.

I would suggest running your program with `runhaskell`:

```
runhaskell Main.hs < in.txt
```